# ARP flux how to solve

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I have a server with 2 NICs having an IP address in the same subnet, this is what my /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.155
  gateway 192.168.2.51
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  dns-nameservers 192.168.2.180
  dns-domain exaple.com

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.2.156
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

So the idea is that eth0 with ip 192.168.2.155 is the 'management' interface with internet connectivity.
The eth1 NIC with IP 192.168.2.156 will be used to communicate with internal devices.

Now When i configure this with a default system, and try to ping eth1 on 192.168.2.156 with other devices on the LAN, these packets are not being received by eth1 as one would expect, but by eth0, I verified this by running `tcpdump -i eth1 icmp`, and can see no packets coming in. The client doing the ping is getting a reply, but from the wrong NIC/MAC address.

Now I've found out that this phenomenon is called 'ARP flux' and even nice articles describing how to solve it, problem is, none of these solutions seem to work for me.
[This article](http://www.jefflane.org/multiple-nics-same-subnet-avoiding-arp-flux) seems to give the best explanation and fix, by running the following commands:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=2
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

This seems to do something, in that I start receiving packets on eth1, but it completely disables any communication on eth0 and IP address 192.168.2.155.

Any other ideas as to what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8401) and [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7775) did you try with?:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
```

Did you fix it?

EDIT:
I mean... everything:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=2
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://wiki.openvz.org/Multiple_network_interfaces_and_ARP_flux) Change to:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter=1
```

Comment: I just tried these but no luck, same result as before i.e.: All traffic shifts from eth0 to eth1 when running these commands

Comment: If eth0 you user only for access from internet, set interface to be in different network.

Comment: Sorry not the answer I was hoping for... For reasons I don't think have to be discussed here, I have to use 2 IP addresses on the same subnet.